# Auto-suggest products based on tags

Tags: commerce

I am interested in autosuggesting products based on the tags an article contains which is read by a user.
How can I accomplish this with Drupal/Drupal Commerce?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which one better fits your use case: 
This blog post has an excellent way to accomplish product suggestions using the Radioactivity module.  http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/drupal-commerce-product-suggestions-with-radioactivity/2013-08-22

There is also the Commerce Recommender module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_rec.
Again, I'm not sure if that is precisely what you're after.

A really straightforward way I could see is create a commerce product view that filters down to only products with the same taxonomy terms on the current article, create a block to hold that view, and display those products with/without their Add to Cart buttons.